# Implementing 3 lists on single page

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am building a simple todo app. I have project model, wich has many todos, files and discussions.

**On project show page I have 3 lists : Todo list, files list and discussion list.**

I started to implement this using JS. I render all lists at the same time and have 3 buttons at the top, each toggling show/hide state of the corresponding list.

Than **I got worried about loading times**, especially with file and discussions lists. File lists need to load files and have slower loading times, and discussions are going to be many, so loading that list will also be time consumable. When all those loading times are added, I'm afraid it will be too slow for pleasant use. (maybe a preoptimisation, but I want to learn right...)

**Am I just being silly and should I proceed with implementing this with JS? Or should I do this different way?**

If so, how? Should I make each list a separate page (project/todos, project/files, project/disussions)? Should I proceed with JS and use pagination to load a set amount of data, keeping loading times bearable?

Comment: I mean, you don't really need to load the whole file in the file list do you? You just need the metadata to show what the download link goes to? This is screenshot_2.jpg, this is project_documentation.docx, etc. And after that, seems like you should scope down the total list of discussions for your main project page to the 5-10 most recent, not every discussion ever.

Comment: ah, wasn't sure exactly how that functions. Ok, I need just the metadata. But the question remains... How to implement this? btw, I can mark the discussions as 'finished' and they will no longer appear in this discussions list. So it won't be every discussion ever, just active discussions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do something like this. Basically set up your associations and apply scopes to them to get the data you need. You'd probably want to then navigate to a nested route for each one to see the whole list, or apply pagination on-page either through rails or JS. If you want to get super crazy you can eager load all these associations, but with 3 associations each with conditions I think that would get crazy pretty quick

Models

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :files
    has_many :discussions, :order => 'updated_at DESC'
    has_many :todos
end
class File < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :project
end
class Discussion < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project

  #scope for last 5 discussions not marked as finished
  def self.recent_unfinished
    where(:finished => false).limit(5)
  end
end
class Todo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project

  def self.undone
    where(:complete => false)
  end
end
```

Controller

```
def show
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    @files = @project.files.select(:filename, :filesize) #assuming you don't want blob data or whatever
    @todos = @project.todos.undone
    @discussions = @project.discussions.unfinished
end
```

Note: I didn't test any of this stuff, so you might have to play with the syntax to get it working :)

Comment: thanks for the code! will play around with it and test it if it is good. btw, for nested route, you mean something like project/files, project/todos etc, right?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say pagination is not only good for load times, but usability (who wants to scroll an enormous list).

You should use ajax (not sure if that is what you meant), and load the intensive stuff after the page has loaded, and show a nice ajax loading icon. You can then easily add a link so the user is required to request this data first.

If you don't use ajax, then be sure to cache these lists.